# Retrofit unit tests to large solution, IOC, Moq

Tags: c#, vb.net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am in the process of retrofitting unit tests for a asp.net solution written in VB.Net and c#.
The unit tests need to verify the current functionality and act as a check for future breaking changes.

The solution comprises of:

1 MVC web project
    written in vb.net (don't ask, it's a legacy thing)

10 other supporting projects each containing logically grouped functionality
    written in C#, each project contains repositories and DAL

All the classes are tightly coupled as there is no inversion of control (IOC) implemented anywhere, yet.

currently to test a controller there is the following stack:

- controller
- - repository
- - - dal
- - - - logging

First question, to unit test this correctly would I setup 1 test project and run all tests from it, or should I setup 1 test project for each project to test the functionality of that DLL only?

Second question, do I need to implement IOC to be able to use MOQ?

Third question, is it even possible to refactor IOC into a huge solution like this?

Forth question, what other options are available to get this done asap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am in the process of retrofitting unit tests for a asp.net solution written in VB.Net and c#. The unit tests need to verify the current functionality and act as a check for future breaking changes.

When working with a large code base that doesn't have unit tests and hasn't been written with testing in mind, there is a good chance that in order to write a useful set of unit tests you will have to modify the code, hence you're going to be triggering the event that you're planning on writing the unit tests to support.  This is obviously risky, but may not be any riskier than what you're already doing on a day to day basis.

There are a number of approaches that you could take (and there's a good chance that this question will be closed as too broad).  One approach is to create a good set of integration tests ensure that the core functionality is working.  These tests won't be as fast to run as unit tests, but they will be further decoupled from the legacy code base.  This will give you a good safety net for any changes that you need to make as part of introducing unit testing.

If you have an appropriate version of visual studio, then you may also be able to use [shims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx) (or if you have funds, typemock may be an option) to isolate elements of your application when writing your initial tests.  So, you could for example create shims of your dal to isolate the rest of your code from the db.

> First question, to unit test this correctly would i setup 1 test project and run all tests from it, or should i setup 1 test project for each project to test the functionality of that dll only?

Personally, I prefer think of each assembly as a testable unit, so I tend to create at least one test project for each assembly containing production code.  Whether or not that makes sense though, depends a bit on what's contained in each of the assemblies...  I'd also tend to have at least one test project for integration tests of the top level project.

> Second question, do i need to implement IOC to be able to use MOQ?

The short answer is no, but it depends what your classes do.  If you want to test using Moq, then it's certainly easier to do so if your classes support dependency injection, although you don't need to use an IOC container to achieve this.  Hand rolled injection either through constructors like below, or through properties can form a bridge to allow testing stubs to be injected.

```
public SomeConstructor(ISomeDependency someDependency = null) {
    if(null == someDependency) {
        someDependency = new SomeDependency();
    }
    _someDependency = someDependency;
}
```

> Third question, is it even possible refactor IOC into a huge solution like this?

Yes it's possible.  The bigger question is it worth it?  You appear to be suggesting a big bang approach to the migration.  If you have a team of developers that don't have much experience in this area, this seems awfully risky.  A safer approach might be to target a specific area of the application and migrate that section.  If your assemblies are discrete then they should form fairly easy split points in your application.  Learn what works and what doesn't, along with what benefits and unexpected pain you're feeling.  Use that to inform your decision about how and when to migrate the rest of the code.

> Forth question, what other options are available to get this done asap?

As I've said above, I'm not sure that ASAP is really the right approach to take.  Working towards unit-testing can be done as a slow migration, adding tests as you actually change the code due to business requirements.  This helps to ensure that testers are also allocated to catch any errors that you introduce as part of the refactoring that might need to take place to support the testing.

Comment: This is a great and very well formulated answer. I couldn't agree with you more.